# Herb infused oil - what went wrong

Tags: oil

I tried to make herb infused oil, but not matter how long I blend it it's still bitty.

I used 250ml of grapeseed oil, 15g of basil, 15g of chives, 15g of parsley, 15g of dill.
I blanched the herbs, then squeezed excess oils out.

I then poured all the oil into my first blender, waring pro. Fail
I then transferred into my magimix and blended again. Still bitty.
I then anded up using a powerful hand blender for about 10mins and I still had bits.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you think that any amount of blending will remove the bits of herb?

Comment: I’m trying to make a very smooth paste like the consistency of pesto to then drain through a muslin to make oil

Comment: Why? Have you read any guidance on how infused oils are created? The guides I've seen use whole herbs that aren't ever blended up... maybe you just need a different method?

Comment: I have never seen a pesto which has the consistency of smooth paste. I only know of chunky pesto.

Comment: It works I’ve seen it done at a cookery school. Also I make smooth pesto all the time.

Comment: I've never seen anyone make herb-infused oil using a blender, so I can't help you.  And I've made quite a bit myself.

Comment: @FuzzyChef actually, the blender is a good idea, since you really want to maximize the surface of cut up cells. If you can avoid strong oxidation, it is very efficient. But it is not supposed to produce a smooth paste, it is supposed to produce tiny pieces of leaves floating in the oil, which the OP got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, funny you should ask that. Just now I am experimenting with using oil and other edible stuff to extract various chemical compounds from herbs without waste of those compounds. Grit or any identifiable vegetable matter is definitely a negative. It is very much the same thing you are talking about because flavor compounds vary in particle size and solubility.

So far, this product has shown great promise in my experimentation:

[image]
They work like cheesecloth, but the filter has holes measured in microns (25 - 220) instead of millimeters. You can wring the heck out of them, wash and reuse. They are constructed kind of like paper grocery bags, each about 1 gallon or 4 liters capacity. The bottom panel is a mesh filter.

It may be an odd off-label use because these things are actually for making hashish, but I saw their culinary potential when I first saw them at a fair. I'm using them now and they really work well to keep infused oils made with ground dried herbs grit-free. You can't wring them too hard, they can handle it.

If a clear, grit-free infused vinaigrette with finely ground dried herbs or food-processed/blended fresh herbs was my goal, I'd definitely give these a shot. Think of them like adjustable, reusable coffee filters.